# Compare two column dates return if they are within 6 months

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query.

```
select distinct m.number --as FirstAccount, m2.number as SecondAccount
from jm_people p
inner join master m on p.accountid = m.number
inner join JM_Subpoena s on m.number = s.number
inner join jm_people p2 on p.pid = p2.pid
inner join master m2 on p2.accountid = m2.number
inner join JM_Subpoena s2 on m2.number = s2.number
and m.number != m2.number
```

I need to compare `s.dateRequested` and `s2.dateRequested` and if they are within or equal to 6 months I need to return the result.

Any ideas on how to do this?

so example:

```
s.dateRequested = '12/18/2013 00:00:000'
s2.dateRequested = '07/27/2013 00:00:000'
```

It would return this result because they are within 6 months

```
s.dateRequested = '12/18/2013 00:00:000'
s2.dateRequested = '03/27/2013 00:00:000'
```

It would not return this result.

Comment: There is DATEDIFF function http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DATEDIFF function http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

```
select distinct m.number --as FirstAccount, m2.number as SecondAccount
from jm_people p
inner join master m on p.accountid = m.number
inner join JM_Subpoena s on m.number = s.number
inner join jm_people p2 on p.pid = p2.pid
inner join master m2 on p2.accountid = m2.number
inner join JM_Subpoena s2 on m2.number = s2.number
and m.number != m2.number
WHERE DATEDIFF( mm, s2.dateRequested, s.dateRequested) < 6 OR
DATEDIFF( mm, s2.dateRequested, s.dateRequested) = 6 
AND DATEPART( dd, s2.dateRequested) <= DATEPART( dd, s.dateRequested)
```

If you need exactly 6 month or less, you can use function DATEPART with days and compare days for case of 6 month and same day or less.

Comment: depending on how precise the OP needs to be, it may be better to use 180 days rather than 6 months; 6/13/2013 is 6 months away from 12/18/2013, but its more than 180 days.

Comment: This will only sort of work.  The DATEDIFF function returns the number of specified boundaries crossed (in this case month boundaries).  So `SELECT DATEDIFF( mm, '2013-12-31 23:59:59', '2014-01-01 00:00:00')` returns 1 even though there is only a 1 second difference.  `SELECT DATEDIFF( mm, '2013-12-01 00:00:00', '2014-01-01 23:59:59')` also returns 1 even though it is much closer to two months.

Comment: Another issue I am running into is from the way the database is setup.  s2.dateRequested could be greater than s.dateRequested.  would it be possible to change it to days and since then would it instead of <= between -180 and 180?  Would that fix my other issue?

Comment: @Becuzz yes, so I've added DATEPART to compare days too.